# linux shell script delimiter

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How to change delimiter from current comma (,) to semicolon (;) inside .txt file using linux command?

Here is my ME_1384_DataWarehouse_*.txt file:

```
Data Warehouse,ME_1384,Budget for HW/SVC,13/05/2022,10,9999,13/05/2022,27,08,27,08
Data Warehouse,ME_1384,Budget for HW/SVC,09/05/2022,10,9999,09/05/2022,45,58,45,58
Data Warehouse,ME_1384,Budget for HW/SVC,25/05/2022,10,9999,25/05/2022,7,54,7,54
Data Warehouse,ME_1384,Budget for HW/SVC,25/05/2022,10,9999,25/05/2022,7,54,7,54
```

It is very important that value of last two columns is number with 2 decimal places, so value of last 2 columns in first row for example is:"27,08"

That could be the main problem why delimiter couldn't be change in proper way.

I tried with:

```
sed 's/,/;/g' ME_1384_DataWarehouse_*.txt
```

and every comma sign has been changed, including mentioned value of the last 2 columns.

Is there anyone who can help me out with this issue?

Comment: First of all, why do you use a <comma> as a decimal separator?

Comment: Probably they are using some legacy junk tool which uses the locale decimal separator, which is comma in many places in Northern Europe. The fundamental lesson is probably "good lord, don't use Excel".

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you can replace the nth occurrence of a certain lookup string. Example:

```
$ sed 's/,/;/4' file
```

will replace the 4th comma with a semicolon.

So, if you know you have 11 fields (10 commas), you can do

```
$ sed 's/,/;/g;s/;/,/10;s/;/,/8' file
```

Example:

```
$ seq 1 11 | paste -sd, | sed 's/,/;/g;s/;/,/10;s/;/,/8'
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8,9;10,11
```

Comment: yes, I got your point, but the thing is, the last 2 columns, their value doesn't have to be a decimal number, it could be whole number as well.

Comment: @MikiNK : Then what is the rule which defines, whether we have a decimal number or an integral number? How would you determine this manually?

Comment: @user1934428 it depens on what I got from the pl/sql procedure which I invoke in a previous step. Is there solution to set delimiter for the .txt file before I run the script?

Comment: This is a completely different problem from what you posted, but basically, if you can not write down a precises specification of how your data has to be interpreted, there is no way that you can write a program to do it; after all, a program is just the implementation of your specification. In your case, it could indeed be that the problem is in the generation of the data, and that you have to change something in this place. Since this is now a new problem, I suggest that you post a new question for this.

Comment: Based on the example in the OP, and assume that the last 4 columns could represent 2,3 or 4 columns, I could come up with a rule to differenciate between 2 floats or 2 integers. However, the case of 3 columns, it is impossible the state which column is the integer.

Comment: ok, thank you guys. appreciate it

Comment: If you know how many columns to expect and there are at most two ambiguous columns, you can write a program which forces each line to the expected number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but if you are trying to say "don't change the last comma, or the third-to-last one", a solution to that might be

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/,(?![^,]+(?:,[^,]+,[^,]+)?$)/;/g' ME_1384_DataWarehouse_*.txt
```

Perl in isolation does not perform any loop over the input lines, but the `-p` option says to loop over input one line at a time, like `sed`, and print every line (there is also `-n` to simulate the behavior of `sed -n`); the `-i~` says to modify the file, but save the original with a tilde added to its file name as a backup; and the regex uses a negative lookahead `(?!...)` to protect the two fields you want to exempt from the replacement. Lookaheads are a modern regex feature which isn't supported by older tools like `sed`.

Once you are satisfied with the solution, you can remove the `~` after `-i` to disable the generation of backups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=";"} {a=$NF;NF-=1; printf "%s,%s\n",$0,a} ' input_file
```

This should work with most `awk` version (do not count on Solaris standard `awk`)
The idea is to store the last element from row in variable, decrease the number of fields and then print using new delimiter, comma and stored last field.

Comment: thanks a lot Romeo, I'll try as you suggested.

Comment: @MikiNK, the solution will work independently of the number of the fields (just to have comma as last delimiter). And my tests show for 4 millions of records `sed` need on my machine ~14s, `perl` ~32s and `awk` ~8s :)

Comment: So, you think that this will work in following example:

`Data Warehouse,ME_1384,Budget for HW/SVC,7,54,7,54,EUR,01/05/2022
 Data Warehouse,ME_1384,Budget for HW/SVC,250,250,EUR,01/05/2022`

Pay attention please on the value of the 2 columns before the last one (in first row is decimal number "7,54" and in the second row the value is whole number "250") because it could be both options, round number and decimal number.

Comment: @MikiNK, which comma need to be saved. And if it is not the last the script need to be refactored. If you have different format maybe will be better to ask different question.

Comment: ...7,54 , 7,54... it suppose to look like 7,54 ; 7,54

Comment: @MikiNK, this is totally different case, please create new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask